# Terminal color don't adapter to terminal theme

Tags: command-line, themes

I have tested this on both Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS and Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, with internet searched. I am a fresh to ubuntu and not a native english speaker. Please forgive my rudeness or error. If any more information is needed, I'm glad to offer.

It seems like terminal is always using dark theme/color. No matter what theme I am using. For instance, when in ubuntu desktop, I changed both my system appearence and terminal theme to light theme(light background with black text), but when I use anything with color like nvim or bat command, the color is exactly the same as they are in dark theme!

So I changed to ubuntu server and test on both that machine and a vps. The same problem happened again.

The only software I installed is zsh, bat and neovim. I can swear that no one of them will cause this happened. As I have them all working well on my Macbook.

For your information, I provide a bad `batcat .bashrc` below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AvgJ.png)

Thank you so much.